# Extract a static value which may change in the future

Tags: c++, assembly

I got the following code in ASM:

```
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+F8]
```

EBX containts an address, F8 is the offset added to this address. If I get this right, eax contains the dereferenced value from address+offset after the operation is executed.

What I want to do now is, to write some pattern in C++ while using inline asm, which allows me to fetch/retrieve F8 without changing the code in case F8 changes.

Is there any pattern search method (like regex) which I can use here? Is the offset possibly saved in any register? Or is this quite impossible to do?

Hopefully the information provided is enough, I could add some more lines of code if you wish.

Comment: Didn't understand what the question was about

Comment: Fetch what from where and why? Please elaborate. (This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Fetch the offset. In this case, F8 is this the offset which is hardcoded in the application. If the application get's recompiled, the offset (F8) may- and will change.

Comment: Well, I have some apples. After I have eaten them and bought some new ones, how do I know which among them are the apples I just ate.

Comment: What's your point here? I'm not very familar with asm but I'm quite sure, that offsets are saved in any register or any line of code. It's okay if there's no way to do this. Anyway thanks for your help solving this issue.

Comment: That offset has to have some meaning to you. You should understand that meaning and try to search relatively to it. Anyway, if source code changed and recompiled the code generated can be too different to find smth not by manual search.

Comment: Okay, thought there is a function which allows me to extract a phrase of the code. Thank you for your help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can add offset to the value in `EBX` register and then get the value from the updated address.

Comment: The problem is that the offset may change. I want to extract the offset which seems to be hardcoded in the application.